# Do we need to enable monitoring for VM in order to monitor Oracle Cloud Compute VM using REST API or Java SDK?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

We have to set policy in IAM for API users in order to be authorized. Other than this, any thing has to done?

Also in different ways of monitoring (REST API, Java SDK, using Oracle Cloud Agent), In which way we need to 'Enable Monitoring'?

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried and what isn't working yet?

Comment: There's a topic [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/enablingmonitoring.htm) that descirbes enable monitoring for compute instances. So, wanted to check if this needs to be done in all the ways of monitoring.

Comment: You have two different kinds of keeping tabs on your VMs in this case, the general REST APIs, which allow you to send all kinds of requests to your OCI objects and the way of monitoring that is mentioned in your link. 
The second is for specific metrics like [these](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Compute/References/computemetrics.htm).

Comment: For the second kind you need to enable monitoring (using the GUI or REST APIs, but not inside the VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please see [this doc](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/enablingmonitoring.htm) for details on the required steps.

Here's an example that shows how to enable / disable instance monitoring from the Java SDK: [link](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/UpdateInstanceExample.java)

Comment: Thanks for your input [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102677/joe)